# How to add a level to component hierarchy in Fusion 360?

Tags: cad

Fusion 360 has the "browser" (tree structure) and timeline to represent the CAD model.

When I realize I should have created a parent component for an already existing component, how to do this?

[image]

In the picture, I wish to create a component `LockBogie` that would wrap the already created component `Lock` underneath it.

I tried this:

- rewinded the timeline to prior of creation of `Lock`
- created `LockBogie` there so it would be available as a parent for `Lock`

Then comes the dead end.

My first intuition was to edit the creation step of `Lock` so I could have reparented it. There's no "edit" or "reparent" option.

Second, I went to the browser. Maybe I can drag `Lock` to be within `LockBogie` (`LockBogie` was the active component when I tried this). Nope. Dragging is not allowed, it seems.

Adding a level of component hierarchy afterwards feels like a relatively common thing that should be no-fuss. If you have done it, please tell how you did it.

---

Disclaimer: This question is particular to one tool. I will likely post it in the Fusion 360 forums as well, but wanted to probe how beneficial the Engineering SO could be in coming to solutions. If the general guidance states the site is for non-tool-related questions only, I will certainly remove this. :)

Comment: Why make a post which you yourself consider is off-topic? The Fusion 360 forum seems a much better choice, or Stack Overflow for software type questions... Is the "disclaimer" just a method to try and avoid downvotes?

Comment: I'd like to see more discussions on the StackExchange platform about any tools. There are some SolidWorks questions around here and I'm just testing the waters, I guess. While I would definitely report bugs etc. at the product forums (same for software vs. Stack Overflow) I'd appreciate the CAD discussions coming out of their silos. That's the main thing, I imagine.